# Using Visual Studio C++ tracepoints to change variables WITHOUT printing output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints

Does anyone know how to use the C++ tracepoint feature "Print a message" without actually printing the message, yet while maintaining the ability to modify variables/memory? I've used tracepoints for years to change variables/memory at runtime but have always suffered the performance cost of Visual Studio printing the result to the Output pane. It would be nice to be able to just modify the memory as an option.

Comment: [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5557y8b4.aspx) says in a section called "Print a message" that you can disable the printing. Or does it still print the value regardless of this option?

Comment: You can disable the tracepoint itself, but not just the printing. Sadly, they seem to have coupled both capabilities (value changing and printing), whereas both would be very useful as separate features.

Comment: Just a thought - is there a way to divert all command line output to a file? If there is, then it will be much less intrusive than the constant screen refresh.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and writing to a file might be at least as slow. The problem really shows up in inner loops where the output is streaming by very quickly. But that's often exactly the situation in which the ability to modify memory is most useful :/